# C# Dynamic aggregate function call using Expression

Tags: c#

Here I trying to create function which will use Expression to call aggreate method like "Min" or "Sum" on `IEnumerable<dobule>`. Somehow not working for "Sum" and "Average". Here is code:

```
Func<IEnumerable<double>, double> BuildFunc(string func)
{
    var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<double>), "source");
    
    //For now added condition to handle it.
    var methodCallExpression = func == "Sum" || func == "Average" 
        ? Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), func, Array.Empty<Type>(), source) 
        : Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), func, new Type[] { typeof(double) },
        source);

    Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(methodCallExpression, typeof(double));

    var methodCall = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<double>, double>>(
        conversion,
        source);
    
    return methodCall.Compile();
}
```

Here is call:

```
IEnumerable<double> myList = new List<double> { 10, 20 };

var func = BuildFunc("Min");
double result = func(myList);

var func = BuildFunc("Sum");
double result = func(myList);
```

How to make this function without adding method name condition?

Comment: _"`BuildFunc(string func)`"_, generally a method that accepts a `string` as a sole parameter as a means to _convey desired functionality_ is an _anti-pattern_.   Callers of your code do not know what is acceptable and what isn't.  e.g. your code will quite happily accept _"Miss Piggy"_ and defaulting to `Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), func, new Type[] { typeof(double) }, source)` to which I don't think Miss Piggy would approve.    Consider using an `enum`.

Comment: @Deleted Yes thank you for that suggestion! Any way to remove hardcoded condition in method implementation?

Comment: What doesn't work? Your code compiles and runs just fine for me? As far as avoiding "stringly typed" data, one common approach is to use Enum.